# What Notation Do I Use To Fix Ambiguity Writing Chain Rule

Tags: calculus, derivatives, notation

I'm a calculus noob learning over the internet. I think the best way to ask my question is just to put up a little diagram I made in paint.

[image]

Now this is my attempt to write the chain rule using d/dx notation:

[image]

So my question is can I use d/dx notation and signify that I'm passing g(x) into the derivative of f(x) without ambiguity as to what I'm doing?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

To write Chain Rule using Leibniz's notation, we have:
$$
\frac{\mathrm d}{\mathrm dx}[f(g(x))] = \frac{\mathrm d}{\mathrm dg(x)}[f(g(x))] \cdot \frac{\mathrm d}{\mathrm dx}[g(x)] 
$$
By letting $u = g(x)$ and $y = f(u)$, we can condense this to be:
$$
\frac{\mathrm dy}{\mathrm dx} = \frac{\mathrm dy}{\mathrm du} \cdot \frac{\mathrm du}{\mathrm dx}
$$

Comment: The *d* means "infinitely small" increments of, so then that would make sense. Thanks!

Comment: Always fun how each discipline has its own notation for differentiating/integrating.